# internal navigation links not working in google chrome

Tags: html, css

```
    <!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="sticky-nav">
        <a id="mobile-nav" class="menu-nav" href="#menu-nav"></a>

        <div id="logo">
            <a id="goUp" href="#home-slider" title="Amy Crews | Graphic Design">a.Crews.com</a>
        </div>

        <nav id="menu">
            <ul id="menu-nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="#home-slider">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work">My Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>
<!-- End Header -->

<!-- Our Work Section -->
<div id="work" class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Title Page -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="title-page">
                    <h2 class="title">Work</h2>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Title Page -->



Here is the .css  

#mobile-nav {
    display: none;  
}

.menu-nav {
    background:url(http://www.acrews.com/_include/img/menu-mobile.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
    margin: 22px 0 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out 0s;    
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
         -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
            transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
}

.menu-nav.open {
    background-position: 0 -16px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
            transform: rotate(-180deg);

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease-out 0s;    
       -moz-transition: -moz-transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
         -o-transition: -o-transform 250ms ease-out 0s;
            transition: transform 250ms ease-out 0s;    
}

#navigation-mobile {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #26292E;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2F3238;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#navigation-mobile li {
    list-style: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #2F3238;
}

#navigation-mobile li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

The top navigation anchor links (home, my work and contact) will not work in Google chrome.  They are simple anchor links.  The navigation will work when it is viewed in safari, or firefox or in mobile view mode. The full website is www.acrews.com.  Suggestions would be great.

I aslo included some CSS I can attach more, incase something is interfering with the code.

Comment: Your site works with an old version of jQuery-One-Page-Nav/jquery.nav.js (it is set in plugins.js). Try to update to @version 3.0.0. => https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

Comment: Wow!  You are Awesome!  I never thought to look there.  GREATLY appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm glad I helped you. :)